# Is there any difference between Sensitivity and Recall?

Tags: machine-learning, precision-recall, model-evaluation, confusion-matrix

In most of the places, I have found that sensitivity=recall. In terms of the Confusion Matrix, the formula for both of these is the same: $TP/(TP+FN)$.
Is there any difference between these two metrics? If not, then why does the same thing has a different name?

Comment: The reason is probably its use in different fields. Recall is more of a production term and sensitivity more of a clinical term. The terms are also more self-explanatory in those fields, so I guess that's why.

Comment: True positive rate is yet another name for the same thing. In my opinion it is the most logical, because you can infer the definition from it: the amount of true positives with respect to all positives.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not uncommon that statistical tools have different origins and names, but same meaning.

The name **sensitivity** comes from the statistics domain as a measure for the performance of a binary calssification, while **recall** is more related to the Information Engineering domain.